# How to provide write Access to root drive in windows server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, root

How to provide write Access to root drive in windows server 2003 for "non-admin" users ?

This is kind of requirement now, and happening in a controlled environment, so dont bother about security issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the permissions, just as you do on any other file or folder.

Comment: I meant write permission to the root drive : `c:\` Not to any folder... I am unable to see any such option for this ?

Comment: Simply right click on the C: drive and use the security tab as usual. The root is just another folder, even though it's displayed as a drive.

Comment: That works :) `right click C: > properties > security > do whatever`
@John Gardeniers Thank you :)